# Read from COM port in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to READ and Write from the Serial Port in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243070/how-to-read-and-write-from-the-serial-port-in-c)

How do I read data from a COM port in C #? More specifically, I need to read data of variable length. If possible please provide an example. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please give more details on what you are trying to do? How is the data being sent to you etc...

Comment: Have you searched through this site? This question has come up _many_ times. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+com+port).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` class or the `System.IO.Ports` namespace.

There are some examples and more information on this [page](http://msmvps.com/blogs/coad/archive/2005/03/23/SerialPort-_2800_RS_2D00_232-Serial-COM-Port_2900_-in-C_2300_-.NET.aspx).

Here is an example:

```
    // This is a new namespace in .NET 2.0
    // that contains the SerialPort class using System.IO.Ports;

 private static void SendSampleData()

 { 

// Instantiate the communications
// port with some basic settings

 SerialPort port = new SerialPort(
    "COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One); 

// Open the port for communications
 port.Open();

 // Write a string 

port.Write("Hello World"); 

// Write a set of bytes 

port.Write(new byte[] {0x0A, 0xE2, 0xFF}, 0, 3); 

// Close the port 

port.Close(); }
```

Comment: This appears to show how to write, while the question asks how to read