# Managing serial ports in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

Does anyone know the easiest way to control a serial port in c# (e.g. set baud rate, data bits, stop bits, read inbound messages in bytes, push outbound messages in bytes,...etc)? Are there any ready classes that I can utilize for this?

Answer (score 7):

You can do all this with the [System.IO.SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class.
 (so long as you're using >NET 2.0 or above.)