# how to read data from serial port and write in a file in c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

i need to open a serial port send command 00 00 F0 00 00  and then receive the data from the port if he command received is F1 and data received is F1 D6 i need to open a file and write the data. and then again send the command F1 and if command received is F2 i need to close the file.

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243070/how-to-read-and-write-from-the-serial-port-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SerialPort Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) in .NET to accomplish this. Use `Read(...)` and `Write(...)` methods to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you add serialPort1 tools in your form and after using

```
if (!sensport.IsOpen)
            {
                foreach (string port in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
                {
                    sensport.PortName = port;
                    sensport.BaudRate = 9600;
                    MessageBox.Show(port + " is open");
                }
                label1.Text = "";
                try
                {
                    sensport.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Please control your connection");
                }               
            }
```

that codes to open your port.

After that you need Write() and Read() method in serialPort1.