# How to implement Serial Port Communication in C# to control a Cash Deposit Machine

Tags: c#, serial-port, serial-communication

My question may be seem too wide, but am kindly requesting for a guide or rather a starting point.

I have a project in which am required to develop a system that will control a Cash Deposit Machine. All activities like getting the amount of notes in the machine and others can easily be done from the system.

During my research, i found out that the machine uses a dll called `libglorycolx2010.dll` and many other modules, and that i can use Serial Port Communication to communicate with the machine.

Has anyone here ever handled such a project? How can this be implemented.Reference tutorials or links will be of great help.

Comment: I do not think that "control" an ATM will be possible to an extent that is more than reading some operational data. Just imagine you could make an ATM dispense all its money by tapping the RS232 ... LOL. Although, I know that you can in some cases read operational data like Card-Numbers, Amount withdrawn etc. - a bit like "tail -f" a logfile - but every manufacturer will have his own protocol.

Comment: You are looking to control a Teller Cash Recycler device manufactured by Glory. The device can be controlled only via it's own API, hence the dll you are talking about, however the API and the SDK are not public domain. You need to contact GLORY or it's partners in your country to obtain the SDK and the manuals for using the interface. As i remember, these devices can be controlled via Serial/USB and ETH. Ask the vendor for drivers and documentation.

Comment: You are very true. The machine is manufactured by Glory and i have the API with me which i obtained from one of their partners. Have you handled the Glory API?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** I searched for documentation related to that dll and was only able to find phishy looking download sites. Assuming you don't have the documentation, your best bet is to contact the manufacturer and/or distributor of the deposit machine and find out who makes the software, and from them obtain the documentation.

The framework has built-in support for serial port comm. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) and a [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1243078/3446285). Make sure to read up on the documentation of the deposit machine to ensure you're using the right port settings.

Comment: Well but then again he is still missing specs of the device itself. He needs to know 'what to send' to the device in most cases, to get the desired answers. So a look into the devices documentation might be useful

Comment: Thanks Koby Duck, that is helpful

Answer (score 0):

SerialPort provide everything you need as a turnkey solution in the .NET Framework. It easily take cares of parameters (Serial Port name, baud rate, and so on), communication, etc. I always use it when doing Serial Communication.

If you need to experiment with SerialPort, install TeraTerm and any software allowing you to virtualize paired serial port on your developing system, so you can experiment quickly and independantly from your target Cash Deposit Machine.

Comment: My main problem is using the libglorycolx2010 dll n the other modules.

Comment: Unless it's badly executed or we're not speaking about the same kind of serial communication (baud rate, data bits, etc), the serial communication should be independant from the implementation. In case that .dll make something wrong that you can't use an all built Serial Communication API, it's impossibly to answer your question without knowing what that dll is doing.