# C# await event and timeout in serial port communication

Tags: c#, serial-port

Hi I have a simple communication on serial port well all is according to book and documentation so open port method looks like this:

```
    public SerialPort OpenPort(string portName)
    {
        Port = new SerialPort(portName, BaudRate);
        try
        {
            Port.Open();
            Port.DtrEnable = true;
            Port.RtsEnable = true;

            Port.DataReceived += DataReceivedEvent;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERRROR: {e.Message}");
        }

        return Port;
    }
```

Here we have an event on data read:

```
    private async void DataReceivedEvent(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = new byte[Port.BytesToRead];
        await Port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(data, 0, data.Length);

        Response = data;

        isFinished = true;
    }
```

Well all is fine and dandy, but now i want to send a message on demand and store response in a property, also i want to add cancellation token on that task timeout. So i came up with this method:

```
        public async Task SendMessenge(byte[] messange)
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
        cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(5000);
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        isFinished = false;
        try
        {
            Task worker = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (!isFinished)
                {
                }
            }, token);

            await Port.BaseStream.WriteAsync(messange, 0, messange.Length, token);
            await worker;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            throw new OperationCanceledException(e.Message, e, token);
        }
    }
```

Problem is with this while loop, if it is task it goes into endless loop, and it does not capture timeout token, if i put it outside a task and remove worker it works but im loosing cancellation token. I guess i could do some manual countdown like:

```
double WaitTimeout = Timeout + DateAndTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
while (!(DateAndTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds >= WaitTimeout)|| !isFalse)
```

But it looks ugly.

So i think my basic question is how to effectively await for event to response and get a timeout?

Comment: `while (!isFinished)
                {
                }`<= this is terrible ...  why not `ManualEventResetSlim` ... more over it has `Wait(timeout)` ...

Comment: Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine and yours is suboptimal. For starters, you are going on after a fatal exception and do not properly log/expose stuff. here are two articles on the mater I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: change `isFinished` from `bool` to `ManualEventResetSlim` like `ManualEventResetSlim 
 isFinished=ManualEventResetSlim ();` instead setting it to `false/true` use `Reset/Set` then instead `await worker` use `isFinished.Wait(Timeout)`

Comment: Do you know how many bytes to expect in response?

Comment: It turns out my original answer was completely wrong as `SerialPort` asynchronous API ignores timeout properties completely. Please check the update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read data in a loop after write operation until get a full response. But you need to use synchronous API and `Task.Run()` as current version of the asynchronous API ignores `SerialPort` timeout properties completely and `CancellationToken` in Task based API almost completely.

Excerpt from the [SerialPort.ReadTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readtimeout?view=netframework-4.7.2) Microsoft Docs that is relevant to `SerialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync()` because it uses default implementation `Stream.ReadAsync()`:

> This property does not affect the [BeginRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.beginread?view=netframework-4.7.2) method of the stream returned by the [BaseStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.basestream?view=netframework-4.7.2) property.

Example implementation using synchronous API and dynamic timeout properties update:

```
static byte[] SendMessage(byte[] message, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    // Use stopwatch to update SerialPort.ReadTimeout and SerialPort.WriteTimeout 
    // as we go.
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    // Organize critical section for logical operations using some standard .NET tool.
    lock (_syncRoot)
    {
        var originalWriteTimeout = _serialPort.WriteTimeout;
        var originalReadTimeout = _serialPort.ReadTimeout;
        try
        {
            // Start logical request.
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = (int)Math.Max((timeout - stopwatch.Elapsed).TotalMilliseconds, 0);
            _serialPort.Write(message, 0, message.Length);

            // Expected response length. Look for the constant value from 
            // the device communication protocol specification or extract 
            // from the response header (first response bytes) if there is 
            // any specified in the protocol.
            int count = ...;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[count];
            int offset = 0;
            // Loop until we recieve a full response.
            while (count > 0)
            {
                _serialPort.ReadTimeout = (int)Math.Max((timeout - stopwatch.Elapsed).TotalMilliseconds, 0);
                var readCount = _serialPort.Read(buffer, offset, count);
                offset += readCount;
                count -= readCount;
            }
            return buffer;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Restore SerialPort state.
            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = originalReadTimeout;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = originalWriteTimeout;
        }
    }
}
```

And example usage:

```
byte[] request = ...;
TimeSpan timeout = ...;

var sendTask = Task.Run(() => SendMessage(request, timeout));
try
{
    await await Task.WhenAny(sendTask, Task.Delay(timeout));
}
catch (TaskCanceledException)
{
    throw new TimeoutException();
}
byte[] response = await sendTask;
```

You can do similar thing with `CancellationToken` instance and use `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` between read and write operations but you have to make sure that proper timeouts are set on `SerialPort` or otherwise Thread pool thread will hang forever possible holding a lock. As far as I know you can't utilize `CancellationToken.Register()` because there is no `SerialPort` method to call to cancel an operation.

For more information check:

- [Top 5 SerialPort Tips](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2006/10/10/top-5-serialport-tips-kim-hamilton/) article by Kim Hamilton
- [Recommended asynchronous usage pattern of SerialPort](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/36040), [Document that CancellationToken in Stream.ReadAsync() is advisory](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25154) and [NetworkStream.ReadAsync/WriteAsync ignores CancellationToken](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/15033) related issues on .NET GitHub
- [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) article by Stephen Toub