# Enforce a "bytes threshold" on ReadAsync

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I need some help reading data from a serial port connected to a device with an RS-232 interface. I decided to use an `async`/`await` style since there will be data constantly updating in a GUI, which should remain user-responsive.

The code below is the essence of my current implementation.

```
private async void MyReadFromSerialPortMethod()
{
    // (this.serialPort is a System.IO.Ports.SerialPort instance.)
    this.serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
    this.serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();

    this.serialPort.Write(/* bytes for "please send me some data now", 0, length */);

    byte[] header = new byte[3];
    await this.serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(header, 0, header.Length);

    // do something with the header info first,
    // like check what kind of data is incoming

    byte[] data = new byte[5];
    await this.serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(data, 0, data.Length);

    // do something with the data,
    // like show it to the user eventually
}
```

My issue is that, in the above code, the `ReadAsync` calls usually only read one byte from the input and then return from `await` (not *always*, but usually). If I were using synchronous methods, I could arrange for `ReceivedBytesThreshold` to contain the requisite number of bytes, but don't want to hold the UI thread while I do that. As far as I know, there is no such threshold for `ReadAsync` to delay returning. This would be very helpful.

I have implemented the following as a workaround, but it doesn't feel like a good solution to me. Looping around the asynchronous method feels like I'm just writing a busy-waiting loop to wait for the input buffer to fill, and I might as well use the synchronous version. While I know the `await` probably does return control to the caller to some extent between each byte arriving, this is not a question about profiling code for speed and efficiency, but rather about what the right coding pattern is and if I am taking advantage of asynchronous programming or handicapping it.

```
    byte[] header = new byte[3];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while (bytesRead < header.Length)
    {
        bytesRead += await this.serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(header, bytesRead, header.Length-bytesRead);
    }
    // similarly for byte[] data...
```

Comment: Your code is perfect, it won't eat CPU time and its pretty efficient. how ever you may want to consider cancelling the operation, use `CancellationToken` and throw if cancel is requested by user. put `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` inside the loop

Comment: other solution would be to use `Task.Run` to run synchronous code on another thread.

Comment: You can run a separate thread for `read` and `write` simultaneously on the `BaseStream`. Or Continuously  to `read` in a separate thread with `while(true)`, and write normally.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, thank you for your suggestion, I was considering something like this. I was also considering that this approach might require its own `Timeout` counter in case the device stops sending bytes permanently for some reason.
Also with regard to @Pierre 's comment, I am not sure that I want to make this application explicitly multi-threaded. The advantages seem clear, but I am worried about potential disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a multi byte response you need a loop anyway because `SerialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold` property is only relevant to `SerialPort.DataReceived` event. But probably in request-response scenario you still need to use synchronous API and `Task.Run()` because asynchronous API ignores `SerialPort` timeout properties completely and `CancellationToken` almost completely. That means that asynchronous `SerialPort` operations can hang forever holding buffers and possibly locks.

Also you need to synchronize access to the critical sections (logical blocks of interaction with a serial port), so multiple requests don't intervene with each other (using `lock` keyword, `SemaphoreSlim` instance or similar).

For example implementation please check [C# await event and timeout in serial port communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53335736/c-sharp-await-event-and-timeout-in-serial-port-communication/53633030#53633030) discussion on StackOverflow.

In general you need to perform relevant tests and see if an approach leads to good user experience.

For more information check:

- [Top 5 SerialPort Tips](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2006/10/10/top-5-serialport-tips-kim-hamilton/) article by Kim Hamilton
- [Recommended asynchronous usage pattern of SerialPort](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/36040) issue on CoreFX GitHub
- [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) article by Stephen Toub
- [How to Read and Write from the Serial Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243070/how-to-read-and-write-from-the-serial-port/53864639#53864639) discussion on StackOverflow
- [SerialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.receivedbytesthreshold?view=netframework-4.7.2) page on Microsoft Docs

Comment: Thank you for this thoughtful answer and the links, very much appreciated. I will study them. I also found the following helpful: [If you must use .NET System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport). Can you elaborate on the `Semaphore` usage? My understanding is that semaphores manage multiple-thread access, which doesn't apply when using `await`. It would only apply when using a separate `Task.Run()`, is that right? I agree that I should do more testing, in the end this determines the necessary approach.

Comment: That is a very good question. I had following scenario in mind: imagine that you send a request A to some device, UI thread is now free, device ignores request A because it's software version doesn't support it, asynchronous request A is still in process, you send request B to the device, the device answers to request B because it is a valid request and now UI thread processes response to B as if it is response to A. `Stream` has some internal synchronization mechanism but the exact `SerialStream` behavior is unclear to me. So I would organize critical sections on my side to be sure.

Comment: Research led me to a discovery regarding synchronous vs asynchronous API, please check the update.