# C# serial events when the serial is not in design

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, serial-port

I added this in my code:

```
namespace uartToCs_version_2._0
{
    public partial class formMain : Form
    {
    ==> public static SerialPort serial = new SerialPort();
```

But I didn't use the design tab, so how should I go about event handling (with the current setup I can use it in other forms too, will that still be possible)?
[My design file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbpxL.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Read and Write from the Serial Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243070/how-to-read-and-write-from-the-serial-port)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //add DataReceived event of serial
        Form1.serial.DataReceived += serial_DataReceived;          
    } 
    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        //remove DataReceived event of serial
        Form1.serial.DataReceived -= serial_DataReceived;  
    }
    void serial_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //process data here 
    }
```

Comment: regard  serial is static ,so  in FormColosed event , remove serial_DataReceived event  for gc

Comment: why is this needed?

Comment: if serial is static , it will be collected by GC when it be set to null or app is exit . when Form1 instance closed , Form1 instance probably not been collected by GC , since Form1.serial is living , and  Form1.serial.DataReceived reffer the Form1 instance  by exec Form1.serial.DataReceived += serial_DataReceived.

Answer (score 1):

You can register the events either in any method like Load() or in the constructor.  I used the constructor below.  You can't register event until all the needed properties are setup.  I did not show the setup code.

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static SerialPort serial = new SerialPort();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            serial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serial_DataReceived);
        }


        private void serial_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply