# System.IO.IOException: Too many posts were made to a semaphore

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, serial-port, serial-communication

I'm developing an App in .net (Xamarin) and I'm trying to establish a connection
with a serial port.
Whenever I try to open the connection with the port I'm getting this error_message:

System.IO.IOException: 'Too many posts were made to a semaphore'

Can't find anything specific by googling. Any help appreciated!

Example code:

```
private void Open()   
    {
        IsOpen = true;
        _serialPort.PortName = "COM3";
        _serialPort.BaudRate = 19200;
        _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        _serialPort?.Open();
    }
```

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1243070/102937).

Comment: Try changing `_serialPort?.Open();` to `_serialPort.Open();`

Answer (score 3):

This is because you need to add

```
<DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
      <Device Id="any">
          <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
      </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

to your Package.appxmanifest.

Took me awhile to figure this out myself.